# spring jdbc templates and the best one to use

Tags: java, spring

my question is regarding that which jdbc template must be used most commanly, and what are the disadvantages of using the simple jdbc template though it can be used for both the named as well as the question mark place holders, basically explain me the difference and  which is the best to use as i am new to spring framework.

Comment: ORM framework like Hibernate,IBATIS,JPA it will be good to use with Spring.If you are developing a small application then ORM is not required  you can go with Spring JDBC template over core JDBC.Spring JDBC template has several advantages over core jdbc. If you used ORM then you application will be run independent of database in future you may into the position to change the database.It will not cause code change in DAO layer. Simply small changes in configuration files are enough.

Comment: as iam just learning spring i want to know about the templates used in the spring only, what is diffrence and which one must be used

Answer (score 5):

The JdbcTemplate class executes SQL queries, update statements and stored procedure calls, performs iteration over ResultSets and extraction of returned parameter values. It also catches JDBC exceptions and translates them to the generic, more informative, exception hierarchy defined in the org.springframework.dao package.

Instances of the JdbcTemplate class are threadsafe once configured. So you can configure a single instance of a JdbcTemplate and then safely inject this shared reference into multiple DAOs.

A common practice when using the JdbcTemplate class is to configure a DataSource in your Spring configuration file, and then dependency-inject that shared DataSource bean into your DAO classes, and the JdbcTemplate is created in the setter for the DataSource.

Spring provides hibernate template and it has many advantages like

1) It removes boiler plate code like getting connection from data source, try/catch block for closing connection. So that developer can focus on writing business logic rather then writing boilier plate code every where.

2) Spring hibernateTemplate also throws RunTime exception compared to checkd exception which allows to remove writing try/catch block in each DAO.

3) It also gives richer template class, using which developer can write query code easily. This template class also allows to get session explicitly, so if developer wants to get session object and work on it, then it's possible.

which one is best for you dependent on your requirements